# Android BLE foreground service

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I am having some trouble with BLE communication working on a foreground service. 
Although the logic on the service works fine, if the activity is open, every time a Bluetooth device is in range my service does what it has to do. But after I close or suspend the activity, my service only works one time and it seems that it ignores the scan callback and doesn't do anything.

The expected behavior should be that even when the main activity is closed, the service should find and do the associated logic.

```
public class DeviceControlService extends Service implements  BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback{
private String TAG = "In Service --> ";
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;                                         //BluetoothAdapter represents the radio in the Smartphone
private boolean mScanning;                                                          //Keep track of whether there is a scan in progress
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 100000;                                      //Length of time in milliseconds to scan for BLE devices

private String wantedDevice = "00:1E:C0:29:2A:BE";
private boolean found = false;
InServiceControl deviceControl;
private boolean switchStatus = true;
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

private States state = IDLE;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private  BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback;

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    DeviceControlService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return DeviceControlService.this;
    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

public void stopThread(){
    Log.d(TAG, "thread stoped");
    stopScanning();
    switchStatus = false;
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.d(TAG, "On start");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    state = INIT;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("MBO")
            .setContentText("Bluetooth is running.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tooth)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(101, notification);
    adapterInit();
    scanLeDevice();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(switchStatus)
                states();
        }
    }).start();
}





@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    deviceControl = null;
    bluetoothManager = null;
    mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void adapterInit(){
    Log.d(TAG, "in adapter init");
    bluetoothManager = (android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE); //Get the BluetoothManager
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    deviceControl = new InServiceControl(mBluetoothAdapter, this);

}

public void states(){

    switch(state){
        case IDLE:
            break;
        case INIT:
            switchStatus = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "init");
            if(mBluetoothAdapter == null){
                adapterInit();
            }
            state = PROCESSING;
            break;
        case PROCESSING:
            if(!mScanning){
                scanLeDevice();
            }else{
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;

        case DONE:
            Log.d(TAG, "done");

            state = PROCESSING;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Scan for BLE device for SCAN_PERIOD milliseconds.
// The mLeScanCallback method is called each time a device is found during the scan
private void scanLeDevice() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered into scanning");

    if(!mScanning){
        Log.d(TAG, "started Scanning");
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
        mScanning = true;
    }

}

private void stopScanning(){
    Log.d(TAG, "scanning stoped");
    if(mScanning) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
        mScanning = false;
    }
}


public void autoConnect(BluetoothDevice device){
                                                                      //Stop the scan in progress
    deviceControl.init(device.getName(), device.getAddress());
    state = DONE;

}


    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) { //Android calls method with Bluetooth device advertising information

        if(device.getAddress().equals(wantedDevice)){
            stopScanning();
            autoConnect(device);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Found BLE Device: " + device.getAddress()  ); //Debug information to log the devices as they are found
    }
```

Is it possible that android is ignoring the scan callback for some reason that i am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same problem here! :-(

Comment: Please refer to my answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68452095/android-bluetooth-le-scanner-on-foreground-service-stops-immediately-when-screen/68560159#68560159