# Android Bluetooth LE scanner on foreground service stops immediately when screen turns off

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have the following BLE foreground service implementation -

```java
public class BluetoothForegroundService extends Service {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK , this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "BLE test")
                .setContentTitle("Bluetooth Service")
                .setContentText("Fetching Bluetooth")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        BluetoothScanner bluetoothScanner = BluetoothScanner.getInstance(new BluetoothScanner.OnBlePacketBuilderListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBleObjectsCreated(BleBeaconPacketData beaconPacketData, BleHardwarePacketData bleBroadcastPacketData) {
                if (bleBroadcastPacketData == null && beaconPacketData == null) return;
                Log.d("onBleObjectsCreated", "onBleObjectsCreated");
                Intent intent = new Intent("action");
                if (beaconPacketData != null)
                    intent.putExtra("BleBeaconPacketData", beaconPacketData);
                if (bleBroadcastPacketData != null)
                    intent.putExtra("BleHardwarePacketData", bleBroadcastPacketData);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
        bluetoothScanner.startBluetooth();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```java
public class BluetoothScanner implements BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback, BlePacketBuilder.BlePacketBuilderListener {

    interface OnBlePacketBuilderListener{
        void onBleObjectsCreated(BleBeaconPacketData beaconPacketData, BleHardwarePacketData bleBroadcastPacketData);
    }

    private final OnBlePacketBuilderListener listener;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    public static BluetoothScanner instance;

    private BluetoothScanner(OnBlePacketBuilderListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public static BluetoothScanner getInstance(OnBlePacketBuilderListener listener) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new BluetoothScanner(listener);
        return instance;
    }

    public void startBluetooth() {
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = MainApplication.getPureTrackApplicationContext().getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        if ((bluetoothManager != null ? bluetoothManager.getAdapter() : null) == null) return;
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this);
    }

    public void stopBluetooth() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) return;
        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        Log.d("BluetoothScanner", "New BLE - " + Arrays.toString(scanRecord));
        BlePacketBuilder blePacketBuilder = new BlePacketBuilder(this);
        blePacketBuilder.parseResult(bluetoothDevice, rssi, scanRecord);
    }


    @Override
    public void onfinishedToParseResults(BleBeaconPacketData beaconPacketData, BleHardwarePacketData bleBroadcastPacketData) {
        listener.onBleObjectsCreated(beaconPacketData, bleBroadcastPacketData);
    }
}
```

And on my MainActivity I am receiving the broadcast  -

```java
private void getBluetoothDataFromForegroundService() {
        registerReceiver(new BluetoothScannerReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (powerManager == null) return;
                Log.d("onReceiveBle", "onReceiveBle");

                //At this point data is handled both for UI and for network calls 
            }
        }, new IntentFilter("action"));
    }
```

The thing is that I need the BLE to keep sampling data even when the screen is off forever. This is an internal product so I do not care about battery consumption or anything that normal applications users would be worried about. I just need to sample the BLE forever and handle the data accordingly with network calls.

I tried to use WakeLock and it did not help. I am not gettings logs when the screen shuts down and gettings the logs back when the screen turns on back. What is it that I am missing for the BLE to keep sampling?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are lacking some things.

> Android 10 permissions
> On Android 10, you generally must have obtained ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION for beacon detection to work when your app is not visible. However, it is possible to scan with only foreground location permission granted and a foreground service if you add android:foregroundServiceType="location" to your foreground service declaration in the manifest. See here for details.

So you need **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** in order to get scanning results when the screen is off in A10+.

Also, has introduced in A8, (you can see it [here](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2019/04/30/the-rise-of-the-nasty-forks)), there is a limit of 10 minutes before **scan function** stops. So I recommend you to use a **JobScheduler** or a **Runnable** to make a **9 minutes timer** (or 10) and reset the scan. That way you get a long scanning service. This is an example:

```
 mHandlerUpdate?.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

        mHandlerUpdate?.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                Log.d(BleService::class.java.simpleName, "run: in runnable handler")
                scanner.stopScan(mScanCallback)

                scanner.startScan(
                    filters,
                    settings,
                    mScanCallback
                )
                mHandlerUpdate?.postDelayed(this, 60000)
            }
        }, 60000)
```

The handler above resets the scanning every 60 seconds. Is just a demo code. You can modify accoriding to your needs. Remember to **removeCallbacksAndMessages** when you are done with it.

Also, it is necessary to have Location Services on in order to get results. You can see the why [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065090).

Some other links of interests..

[Chet talk](https://youtu.be/D2cU_itNDAI?t=1286)

[Develpers Android Bt Page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback))